# Parametrize batch file so that it can pick up anyone's python distribution to run script

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I have a common drive with my colleagues where we put python scripts and I want to create a batch file in it , which everyone can run in order to execute a python script.

I have tried using pyinstaller to create an executable BUT it is so slow (and I haven't used the --onefile option!!), actually it always spends so much time on "Matplotlib is building the font cache...." plus it took so long to build

So, my question; How can I configure/parametrize a batch file in notepad so that it can pick the python distribution of whoever's running it?

To become more clear, when building the .bat file I input:

```
"Path where my Python exe is stored\python.exe" "Path where my Python script is stored\script name.py"
pause
```

Instead of picking only my python distribution, I would like it to automatically pick up anyone's.

Thank you

Comment: Well you'd need to search the end users system to see if they had a `python.exe` file, and if they had none, close, and if they had several, ask them to identify which they'd prefer to use as a working exectuable. As there's no specific way to guarantee that your end user will have python installed, and if they did have, which versions, and if several, their preferred version, and their respective locations, your best course of action would be to create a single executable file/package instead.

Comment: We all have the same version. Thanks for the comment. However, practically is there any “code” understandable by the cams I can write in the bat file so that it can pick up anyone’s python?

Comment: You can have multiple python versions, including 32-bit and 64-bit, on the same system at the same time, each located in common or uncommon locations, and with no standardized method of identifying them. So as I implied previously, unless all of the units were imaged/setup, and rigorously configured with exactly the same software, then audited regularly to prevent other things subsequently being added or removed, I'd say no, you'll probably need to follow my previous advice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well everything is the same installation from it the only thing that changes is the username that is what I am saying. Literally everything is the same

Comment: So if the location is always somewhere within the users profile directory, there are built-in environment variables to assist you with your issue. If the location was `C:\Users\<users name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`, then you'd replace that with `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python38`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `set`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and take a look at the variables available, perhaps `%UserName%`, and `%UserProfile%` could also be useful to you.